# Munin interrupted graph for today, but normal for days ago

Tags: performance, centos, system, monitoring, munin

I have a trouble with munin plugins (it lasts about a month). One of plugin's view looks like:
[image: Broken munin graph]

But, when i go to see this period 2 days ago, graph has normal view. But i am sure, 2 days ago this period was broken/interrupded.

Any ideas how i can fix that? A lot of thanx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, gaps in graphs are a result from the munin server not being able to contact the node. This can be because the server is too busy (too many nodes to process), the node is too busy or unreachable, or the network is down.

In this case, there are regular 15 minute intervals at suspiciously accurate intervals. This usually points to a scheduled job of some sort, which causes munin to fail at these times:

- 6:55 to 7:10
- 7:55 to 8:15
- 8:55 to 9:10
- 9:55 to 10:10
- 10:55 to 11:10
- 11:55 to 12:10

I'd start my investigation with monitoring CPU, Disk and Network activity manually on both the server and the node simultaneously between 10:55 and 11:10 (using `top` and `ping` will give you a ballpark idea)